# Add imagedata to Bitmap in raw bytes

Tags: c, bitmap

I am trying to add imagedata to an existing bitmap.

The existing bitmap is stored in an byte array:

That's how the image looks like: [image]

If I want to add, let's say 2 lines of blue to the bottom, how could I do that?

```
#include <Windows.h>

const char tred[] = {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC8,0xD1,0xF8,0x95,0xA7,0xF4,0x65,0x80,0xED,0xB0,0xBC,0xF6,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xD0,0xD7,0xFA,0x48,0x68,0xEB,0x01,0x2E,0xE2,0x06,0x30,0xE4,
0x12,0x3A,0xE4,0x0D,0x36,0xE5,0x71,0x8A,0xEF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF4,
0xF6,0xFD,0x35,0x58,0xE9,0x00,0x2B,0xE3,0x19,0x40,0xE6,0x21,0x46,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,
0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xAD,0xBA,0xF6,0x00,0x27,0xE3,0x1A,0x41,0xE6,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0x94,0xA6,0xF2,0x00,0x28,0xE3,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xBB,0xC6,0xF7,0x00,0x27,0xE2,0x22,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x2C,0xE3,0x20,0x46,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x67,0x82,0xEE,0x13,0x3C,0xE5,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,
0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x2C,0xE3,0x20,0x46,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xC3,0xCD,0xF8,0x07,0x31,
0xE4,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0x8B,0x9F,0xF1,0x13,0x3B,0xE5,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,
0x00,0x00,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x17,0x3E,0xE5,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0x79,0x8F,0xF0,0x17,0x3E,0xE5,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0x8E,0xA2,0xF2,0x12,0x3A,0xE5,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xC9,
0xD1,0xF9,0x05,0x30,0xE4,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x04,0x2F,0xE3,0x20,0x46,0xE6,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,
0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x75,0x8C,0xEF,0x11,0x3A,0xE5,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0x05,0x2F,0xE3,0x20,0x46,0xE6,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xD0,0xD7,0xF9,0x00,0x25,0xE3,0x21,0x47,
0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,
0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xAE,0xBC,0xF6,0x00,0x26,0xE3,0x20,0x46,0xE6,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,
0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC8,0xD1,0xF8,0x02,0x2D,0xE3,0x15,0x3D,0xE6,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x21,
0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFE,0x51,0x6F,0xEB,0x00,0x27,0xE3,0x16,0x3D,0xE6,0x1F,0x46,0xE6,0x22,0x47,0xE7,0x21,0x47,0xE7,0x17,0x3E,0xE6,0x78,0x90,0xF0,0x00,0x00,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xEB,0xEF,0xFC,0x65,0x7E,0xEE,
0x0C,0x36,0xE3,0x00,0x2A,0xE3,0x0D,0x36,0xE4,0x0A,0x34,0xE4,0x70,0x89,0xEF,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE4,0xE8,0xFC,0xAE,0xBC,0xF6,0x7E,
0x94,0xF0,0xBD,0xC7,0xF7,0x00,0x00 };


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;

    bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);;
    bmih.biWidth = 14;
    bmih.biHeight = 96;
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biBitCount = 24;
    bmih.biCompression = 0;
    bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

    bmfh.bfType = 19778;
    bmfh.bfSize = ((bmih.biWidth * bmih.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmih.biHeight;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); // 54
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;

    char* bmpData = (char*)malloc(bmfh.bfSize);

    memcpy(bmpData, tred, sizeof(tred));

    HANDLE h = CreateFile("C:\\tmp\\a.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
    DWORD d;
    WriteFile(h, &bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), &d, 0);
    WriteFile(h, &bmih, sizeof(bmih), &d, 0);
    WriteFile(h, bmpData, bmfh.bfSize, &d, 0);

    CloseHandle(h);
    delete[] bmpData;
    return 0;
}
```

What I do not understand: Original file is 14px*24px = 366px in total. In a 24bit Bitmap, there is RGB (3 Bytes) for each pixel, so that would be 366*3=1008bytes. The original file (without header) has 1056bytes.

Maybe that's the reason why my approach, by adding 14*3=42bytes of 0xFF did not add an extra line?

Comment: 42 bytes for each line is **not** multiple of *4*. So *2* padding bytes are added in the end to make them 44, which is multiple. The logic goes `44 * 24 = 1056`. The 2 padding bytes for each line they are not color information.

Comment: The values of `tred` array are not valid for a *bmp* image. The image you are having in the link is a png one!